# Converting elements of a list from str to int

Tags: python

I'm working on a program that involves two lists: one that is just the numbers 1-5 in a random order and one that is just five words saved as different elements. Basically I want to be able to print out the words in the random order of the first list. I've tried:

```
order = ["2","5","4","1","3"]
words = ["Apple","Boat","Carrot","Dragonfly","Education"]
for i in range (0,5):
    print(words[order])
```

and it just says "`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list`".
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: The desired output would be: `Boat \n Education \n Dragonfly \n Apple \n Carrot`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correcting your code would look like this:

```
order = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
words = ["Apple","Boat","Carrot","Dragonfly","Education"]
for i in range(0,5):
    print(words[int(order[i])])
```

But this is nowhere near a clean solution. You are messing with the `index`es far too much.

A better way to do this would be this:

```
for x in order:
    print(words[int(x)-1])
```

---

All this said, there is nothing *random* about what you are doing. Consider using `random.shuffle()` for that. Like so:

```
from random import shuffle

order = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
words = ["Apple","Boat","Carrot","Dragonfly","Education"]
shuffle(order)  # the shuffling is done in-place

for i in [int(c)-1 for c in order]:
    print(words[i])

# prints
Carrot
Dragonfly
Education
Boat
Apple
```

Comment: If you suggest `shuffle`, then you could as well simply shuffle `words` and get rid of `order` entirely.

Comment: @mkrieger1 i would happily do that but that is what OP wants. At least what I understood that he wants

Comment: The `order = ["2","5","4","1","3"]` was just n example, I have another bit of code that generated the order with `order = [] \n
while len(order) != 10: \n
    add = random.randint(1,10) \n
    if add in order: \n
        continue \n
    else: \n
        order.append(add)`

Comment: @ReesK Then you can use any of the two code snippets above the separator line. Or the answer by WillemVanOnsem.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Thanks, I didn't know about the shuffle command and it really helps :)

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems here:

1. you do not fetch the elements of `order`, you simply pass the entire list as index; and
2. as the error says, you should convert the string `'2'` to a the integer `2`.

We can use **`int(..)`** for this. A new problem arises now: lists have zero-based indices, and the indices in your list are one-based. We can however subtract one from it.

This results in the following approach:

```
for i in order:
    print(words[int(i)-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
words = ["Apple","Boat","Carrot","Dragonfly","Education"]
# 1 #
for _ in range(11):
    print(words[random.randrange(0, len(words))])
# 2 #
print("Before shuffle: ",words);random.shuffle(words);print("After shuffle: ",words)
# 3 #
print("Choose 1 random sample",random.sample(words, 1))
```

I dont know what is your aim, but here is what I come up with.
Also you don't need to store them as str in 'order' list. You can have a list of integers, and you can use it without needing to convert. Such as: order=[1,2,3,4,5]

I hope my answer was helpful.Cheers!